How to reduce spacing between columns inside v-table vuetify?
I'm trying to adjust the width of table and columns inside v-table and want to make the table more compact. But, none of them are working.

I want this table to have minimum width as possible with equal column width and I want to make it look aesthetic.
Here's the code
<template lang="">
  <v-dialog>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props: activatorProps }">
      <v-btn
        v-bind="activatorProps"
        color="surface-variant"
        text="Open Dialog"
        variant="flat"
      ></v-btn>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
      <v-card>
        <v-table density="compact" class="border-thin" fixed-header>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">#</th>
              <th class="text-left">INFO</th>
              <th class="text-left">WARN</th>
              <th class="text-left">ERROR</th>
              <th class="text-left">ENTRY</th>
              <th class="text-left">TRACE ERROR</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, key) in tracelogMaskData">
              <td>
                {{ key }}
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox
                  v-bind:id="`info${key}`"
                  :value="`info${key}`"
                  v-model="checkedData"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox
                  v-bind:id="`warn${key}`"
                  :value="`warn${key}`"
                  v-model="checkedData"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox
                  v-bind:id="`error${key}`"
                  :value="`error${key}`"
                  v-model="checkedData"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox
                  v-bind:id="`threadentry${key}`"
                  :value="`threadentry${key}`"
                  v-model="checkedData"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-checkbox
                  v-bind:id="`tracefunc${key}`"
                  :value="`tracefunc${key}`"
                  v-model="checkedData"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-table>
        <hr />
        <v-row class="justify-end">
          <v-col cols="1">
            <v-btn block color="black" rounded="2" @click="applyTraceMaskChanges()">Apply </v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="1">
            <v-btn block color="black" rounded="2" @click="clearTraceMaskChanges()"
              >Clear all
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="1">
            <v-btn block color="black" rounded="2" @click="selectAll()">Select all </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <!-- <v-btn variant="plain" @click="applyTraceMaskChanges()">Select all </v-btn> -->
      </v-card>
    </template>
  </v-dialog>
  <!-- <v-btn block color="black" rounded="2"> DEBUG SELECTION </v-btn> -->
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
const masks = ref({ value: ['info', 'warn', 'error', 'threadentry', 'tracefunc'] })

</script>
<style>

.v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th,
td {
  min-width: 30px !important;
}
</style>

I tried using classes to override default classes as well as css selectors. What changes should I make?

the table uses the full width available to it.  you may want to try something like .v-table { max-width: 500px } or similar.  you can also constrain the width of the v-card or v-dialog to achieve the same effect.

or you can do .v-table{max-width: min-content;} and control the column width using cell padding or min width on the columns or something similar

In order to have the minimum width of the table in an aesthetic way, you can change the width of its container, in your case, the v-card.
For example:
<v-card class="w-50">
    <v-table ...

And don't forget to remove unnecessary styles.
